# Using array of objects with unknown index

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

So, I have a class about workers in a factory. And I have another class with the stuff being sold in the factory. That's OK.

Now, I want to create in the main(), a program that will ask the user to input information about worker or something new in the factory and meanwhile keep using the same object(s) (array of objects).

But I'm not sure how would I make it work.. how to declare it? I am aware that I can create 'MyClass MyObject[1000]'; but that's not a good solution for me, I am looking for a more general one.

So, I have class: MyClass Workers and MyClass Thing. Now I want in main, to ask user whether he wants to input a new workers or thing. And depends which one he chooses, he will be directed to input information about it, then it will ask him again what does he want to input, and it will end when he wants to. So, how do I create an array of objects with the correct size (depending when the user wants to close the program).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use a `std::vector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid new/delete operation where it is possible.

You can create

```
std::vector<MyClass> myclass;
```

And use it then as you want to. pushing objects, pop objects. std::vector will care about memory you use.

Just be sure *MyClass* have copy operator, copy constructor and destructor well defined, if your class is not POD.